# Zend Forms Module Include Paths

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm using Zend 1.8.4 and setting up a simple form test. My form class is located in './application/forms/SectorSearch.php' and the class name is

```
<?php
class Form_SectorSearch extends Zend_Form
{...}
```

My controller creates a new form in the init() method

```
<?php
class SectorController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    function init()
    {
        $this->initView();
        $form = new Form_SectorSearch(array(
            'method' => '/public/sector/search',
            'action' => 'post'));
        $this->view->form = $form;
    }
..
}
```

But i'm getting this error

```
Warning: Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource::include(/home/poconnell/projects/bhaa/application/forms/SectorSearch.php) [zend-loader-autoloader-resource.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/poconnell/projects/bhaa/library/Zend/Loader/Autoloader/Resource.php on line 178

Warning: Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource::include() [function.include]: Failed opening '/home/poconnell/projects/bhaa/application/forms/SectorSearch.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/poconnell/projects/bhaa/library:/home/poconnell/projects/bhaa/application:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/poconnell/projects/bhaa/library/Zend/Loader/Autoloader/Resource.php on line 178

Fatal error: Class 'Form_SectorSearch' not found in /home/poconnell/projects/bhaa/application/controllers/SectorController.php on line 19
```

I'm 100% sure the class is on the include path.

I think this is a bootstraping issue, and this is how i'm loading the default module

```
protected function _initAutoload()
{   
    //Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource  - Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader
    $moduleLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
        'namespace' => '', 
        'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH
    ));
    return $moduleLoader;
}
```

I even tried using this pattern , as recommended by [Autloading modular forms & models in Zend Framework 1.8](http://think-robot.com/2009/07/autloading-modular-forms-models-in-zend-framework-18/)

```
protected function _initAutoload()
{   
    //Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource  - Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader
    $moduleLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
        'namespace' => '', 
        'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH,
        'resourceTypes' => array (
            'form' => array(
            'path' => 'forms',
            'namespace' => 'Form'))
    );
    return $moduleLoader;
}
```

but no joy. any ideas?

Comment: Take care that the filenames are in UperCase as you include them. This is common problem when switching from win to linux.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the file has the correct permissions?

Comment: poconnell@foundry:~/projects/bhaa/application/forms$ ls -al SectorSearch.php 
-rw-r--r-- 1 poconnell poconnell 561 2009-10-15 14:41 SectorSearch.php

Comment: What is the value of APPLICATION_PATH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the case matches exactly.
The folder has to be named **Forms** unless you specified different directory for `Form` classes and make sure **SectorSearch** is not `sEcTorSEarcH.php` or something

Answer (score 2):

I added the following to my Bootstrap.php file

```
protected function _initAutoload()
    {
        $autoloader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
            'namespace' => '',
            'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH,
            'resourceTypes' => array(
                'form' => array(
                    'path' => 'forms',
                    'namespace' => 'Form',
                ),
                'model' => array(
                    'path' => 'models',
                    'namespace' => 'Model',
                ),
            )
        ));
        return $autoloader;
    }
```

and now it works, no errors anymore.. damn i'm glad it works, i was almost going mad.. :)

Comment: Do you know if there's a config entry that you can add to have this be found?

Answer (score 0):

Zend Framework interprets underscores in Class names as folders.  If you are manually adding the application/forms folder to the include path, then you should name your class FormSectorSearch (and the filename FormSectorSearch.php) instead of Form_SectorSearch.  Otherwise you would only add the application folder to the include path and then named the folder Form instead of forms.