# Zend Framework - Form class not autoloading

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm getting

> Fatal error: Class 'Form_Login' not found in /route/to/project/application/controllers/AuthController.php on line XX

when instantiating the class From_Login inside the controller.
I suppose the form is not being autoloaded by the bootstrap class.
In my bootstrap file I have this method

```
protected function _initAutoload(){
        $modelLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
                        'namespace' => '',
                        'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH));
        return $modelLoader;
    }
```

supposed to autoload my resources.
I'm using the default project structure.

```
-application
 --controllers
 ---Authcontroller.php
 --forms
 ---Login.php
```

when I created the form with zf tool it automatically set the name as Application_Form_Login  then I erased the Application_ part since I'm using "" namespace. I doesn't work either way.
I've also tried setting appnamespace="" in the application.ini file but nothing happened

Comment: I found a similar question( http://stackoverflow.com/q/1572271/931340 ) solved by using Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource and then setting the paths and namespaces manually but it didn't worked for me.
I've checked the folders and files names and they seem to be Ok

Comment: All looks ok - your bootstrap is at application/Bootstrap.php, right? (Might be worth checking that is being run), and the form class is defined as `Form_Login` in application/forms/Login.php?

Comment: Yes, that's why I ask, everything looks fine, I can for example instantiate a table in models/DbTable/Table.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying over and over different options I got tired because it didn't work so I erased the project folder and started from the beginning whit zend tool and ... voilà, it works!
In my opinion it was a problem with zend tool and/or the .zfproject.xml file since I was adding some resources manually and some others with the zf tool.

Comment: There must have been something else affecting the class loading. The `.zfproject.xml` file is only read by the `zf` tool. The application does not use it at all. Glad you got it sorted anyway

Answer (score 0):

use Zend modular structure and change your class name 'Form_Login' to 'Default_Form_Login'  .